# How do powers affect asymptotics in generating functions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, power-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers, and $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ its exponential generating function.  Also, suppose $B(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$ is such that, for some $k>0$, $[B(x)]^k = A(x)$.  If an explicit formula exists for the $a_n$ (or just a formula for the asymptotic behavior), what can be derived about the asymptotic behavior of $b_n$, given $k$?

I'm also interested in the analogous problem for ordinary generating functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Flajolet-Sedgewick, Chapter VII (thm VII.8 is relevant) - they talk about asymptotics of algebraic generating functions, of which yours is both a special case ($k$-th root is a very simple algebraic function), and more general ($A(x)$ is not necessarily a polynomial), but they may have a lot more.

(the book is available for free [here](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you, I have been using this book extensively during this project.  I am afraid that I am not strong enough to turn an existence theorem like the one you cite into a practical answer to my question!